# MVC.NET: Use text immediatly after razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In this example (though this issue can happen under other circumstances) I want to take the "id" variable from the Modal and immediately after it (without a space) add ".jpg"

Trying this:

```
<img src="/Images/@Model.Id:@.jpg">
```

Does not work of course (HttpCompileException).

Trying this:

```
<img src="/Images/@Model.Id<text>@.jpg</text>">
```

creates this:

```
<img src="/Images/75<text>.jpg</text>">
```

so that is no good.

I know I can create an extra variable in the Modal with the full path or create it in the Controller and pass it in a ViewBag but I want to know how I can solve it in the .cshtml file for future reference too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, use parenthesis

```
<img src="/Images/@(Model.Id).jpg">
```

Another option is to print `.jpg` as a string

```
<img src="/Images/@Model.Id@(".jpg")">
```

or to concatenate both of them

```
<img src="/Images/@(Model.Id + ".jpg")">
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can do it with this way:

```
<img src='@string.Format("/Images/" + Model.Id +".jpg")'>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what will work for you:

```
<img src="/Images/@(Model.Id).jpg" />
```

The above code will give you this result (if the `id` value is `10001`):

```
<img src="/Images/10001.jpg" />
```

Here is an alternative that you can consider implementing. I used to do it like the code above, but I do it now like this:

```
<img src="@(new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Content("~/Images/10001.jpg")))" />
```

This will result in:

```
<img src="http://localhost:80000/Images/10001.jpg")))" />
```

I hope this helps.